# Converting UTC to local time somewhere else by using pytz

Tags: utc, pytz, astropy

I am trying to convert both sun and f variable to local time in Japan.
My code still gives the output in UTC.

```py
if night_time:
    sun = [float(str(time_now.jd)), float(str(next_sun_rise))]
else:
    sun = [float(str(next_sun_set)), float(str(next_sun_rise))]

if AlwaysBelowTheHorizon:
    pass
elif Circumpolar:
    sun = Time(sun, format='jd')
    if night_time:
        post_message_to_slack("Bingo! We can observe it now until sunrise at {}".format(sun.iso[1]))
    else:
        post_message_to_slack("Sun will set at {}".format(sun.iso[0]))
else:
    if grb_above:
        grb = [float(str(time_now.jd)), float(str(grb_set))]
    else:
        grb = [float(str(grb_rise)), float(str(grb_set))]

    intervals = [sun, grb]
    N = len(intervals)
    f = findIntersection(intervals, N)
    f = f.datetime(timezone('UTC'))
    f = f.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
    post_message_to_slack("We can observe it from {} to {}".format(f[0], f[1]))
```

Comment: Hiya, welcome to StackOverflow and congrats on your first question!  As a note, when posting Python code it's *very important* to make sure it's formatted properly, since proper indentation in Python is significant.  You should make sure to copy/paste it verbatim with all indentation intact.  I've tried reformatted your code sample to what I think was intended but you may want to double-check.

Comment: On another note, your code is missing important context such as how you initialized the variables `time_now` and `grb_rise`, etc. as well as the definition of the `findIntersection` function.  Since your question is about converting astropy `Time` objects to a time in a specific time zone, in the future try to focus the question *just* on that aspect (the minimal steps to perform this task) and not the unrelated stuff like posting messages to slack.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

My comments aside, in case this answers your question, if you have an existing Astropy `Time` object in JD format with UTC scale, you can convert it to a Python timezone-aware `datetime` object with pytz like:

```py
>>> from astropy.time import Time
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> t = Time(Time.now(), format='jd')
>>> t
<Time object: scale='utc' format='jd' value=2459346.8222489627>
>>> tz = timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
>>> dt = t.to_datetime(timezone=tz)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12, 16, 44, 2, 310364, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
```

None of the `float(str(time.jd))` stuff should be necessary either.  For example if you have two existing `Time` objects `sun_rise` and `sun_set` and you want to combine them into a single `Time` array you can already do this:

```py
>>> sun = Time([sun_rise, sun_set])
```

No need for any manual (and error-prone) type conversion shuffling.